# Name for Effect-like Systems that only annotate function types

Tags: language-agnostic

Some languages have ways of tracking properties like purity or the presence/absence of exceptions at compile time. The fact that they do this sort of resembles an effect system.

There seem to be two broad categories of these effect-like systems, one in which any value can be "wrapped in an effect" like the IO Monad in Haskell and one in which only functions can be annotated (like `noexcept` in C++ or checked exceptions in Java). `constexpr` in C++ is a weird case that I don't know how to think about and am intentionally ignoring, since it means very different things when applied to a function and a non-function value.

I'm wondering what you call the Haskell-IO-Monad style of effect tracking vs the checked-exception style. It seems like the only reason you would use the latter is backwards compatibility with a language that doesn't track the effect you're interested in.

More explicitly, Haskell tracks effects at the type level, via the `IO Monad`.

`a -> b` is the type of a pure function with no side effects.
Impure functions return an `IO` value, which has a special status within the runtime / semantics of Haskell.

The nearest equivalent to an impure function in other languages would be something like

`a -> IO b` or, said differently, a computation producing a `b` parameterized by `a`. The type constructor `->` still has the same meaning of `pure function` that it did before.

C++ has a distinction between functions that can potentially throw exceptions (the default) and functions that can't.

```
int add(int x, int y) noexcept {
    return x + y;
}
```

However it isn't possible to mark a non-function as `noexcept`.

```
// BAD!
int x noexcept = <expr>;
```

The `noexcept` applies to the function itself, in effect giving you a different type constructor than `->`.

Comment: You should better use unsigned int in your C example, because while int overflow does not raise an exception, it is subject to undefined behavior which is far worse!